# How to pass struct to a class in c++?

Tags: c++, class, struct

I'm getting these results:

```
constructor 
setFunc 
setFunc
```

Basically I want my class-object globally and pass the struct array to setMethod of the class. and Program is successfully compiling but not getting any results.

```
DataInput.h

#ifndef DATAINPUT_H_
#define DATAINPUT_H_

#include <stdio.h>

struct Data{
    const char *name;
    int salary;
    void set(int salary, const char *name){
        printf("setFunc \n");
        this->name = name;
        this->salary = salary;
    }
};
```

This class in a seprate cpp file with above header file

```
class DataInput {
public:
    int dataSize;
    struct Data data[];

    DataInput();
    virtual ~DataInput();

    void setData(struct Data d[], int numberOfData);
    void printData();

private:

};

#endif
```

-------eof----------
DataInput.cpp

```
#include "DataInput.h"

DataInput::DataInput() {
    printf("constructor \n");
    dataSize = 0;
}

DataInput::~DataInput() {

}

void DataInput :: setData(struct Data d[], int numberOfData){
    dataSize = numberOfData;
    for (int i = 0; i< numberOfData; i++){
        printf("i-val in setData() --> %d",i);
        this->data[i] = data[i];
    }
}

void DataInput::printData(){
    for (int i = 0; i< dataSize; i++){
        printf("name--> %s \n",data[i].name);
        printf("salary--> %d \n",data[i].salary);
    }
}
```

--------eof-----------
main.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "DataInput.h"
#include <stdio.h>


DataInput *dataInput;
int main(void) {
    DataInput in;
    dataInput = &in;

    struct Data d[2];

    d[0].set(1000, "ABC");
    d[1].set(2000, "XYZ");

    dataInput->setData(d, 2); //not setting data
    dataInput->printData(); //not printing
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you mean passing struct to a function of a class?

Comment: yes ... i want to pass struct array to the class

Comment: That won't work. The data[] is an empty array -- it cannot hold anything.

Comment: There's even a bug in `DataInput::setData()`. The input parameter is `d[]` but `this->data[i]` is assigned with itself, `data[i]`.  It should be `this->data[i] = d[i];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a memcpy of the entire array, just assigning the data might lead to memory leaks due to stack frame removal or deletion. This way however you lose the logging simultaneously avoiding the for loop increasing performance

```
void DataInput :: setData(const struct Data const* d, const int numberOfData) {
      // Cleanup old data!
      if(this->data) delete [] this->data;

      if(!d) throw new std::invalid_argument("Cannot set NULL data!"); // Remove this line if NULL may be assigned and replace with the commented code.
      // if(!d) {
      //     this->data = NULL;
      //     this->dataSize = 0;
      // } else {
      this->data = new Data[(this->dataSize = numberOfData)];
      memcpy(this->data, d, sizeof(struct Data) * numberOfData);
      // }
}
```

Don't forget to update the DataInput class!

```
class DataInput {
    public:
        int dataSize;
        struct Data* data;

        DataInput();
        virtual ~DataInput();

        void setData(const struct Data const* d, const int numberOfData);
        void printData();

    private:
};

void DataInput::printData() {
    for (int i = 0; i< this->dataSize; i++){
        printf("name--> %s \n",this->data[i].name);
        printf("salary--> %d \n",this->data[i].salary);
    }
}
DataInput::~DataInput() {
   if(this->data) delete [] this->data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: May not compile, is just illustrative

Few things:

`DataInput`constructor do not reserve space for new items. So, `this->data[i] = data[i];` result is undefined.

This is C++, Rule of three, strings, ....

```
struct Data
{
    std::string name;
    int salary;

    Data(const std::string & n, int s);
    Data & operator=(const Data & d);
};

Data::Data(const std::string & n, int s) :
    name(n), salary(s)
{
}

Data & Data::operator=(const Data & d)
{
    name = d.name;
    salary = d.salary;
    return *this;
}
```

Use standards containers:

```
class DataInput 
{
    private:
        std::vector<Data> data;

    public:
        DataInput();
        virtual ~DataInput();

        // you don't need use size
        void setData(const std::vector<Data> & d);
        void printData();
};

void DataInput::setData(const std::vector<Data> & d)
{
    data = d;
}

void DataInput::printData()
{
    for (std::vector<Data>::iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->name << ":" << it->salary << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Now, you can use it from `main` (without pointers):

```
int main(void) 
{
    DataInput in;

    std::vector<Data> d;

    d.push_back(Data(1000, "ABC"));
    d.push_back(Data(2000, "XYZ"));

    dataInput.setData(d); // yes setting data
    dataInput.printData(); // yes printing
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for using std::vector<Data>; !! Didn't think of it in the first place.